# How to start web server in aws cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have installed odoo webserver using cloudformation. But need to start services manually. How can I start my odoo webserver using cloudformaton?

I tried calling the script which starts odoo webserver by passing following command through `Userdata`.

```
"UserData":{ "Fn::Base64" : "#!/bin/bash sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server start "}
```

But received following error

```
/bin/bash: sudo  /etc/init.d/odoo-server start : No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the first line you posted is commented out with the #:

- "UserData":{ "Fn::Base64" : "#!/bin/bash sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server start "}

It would also help if you posted the full UserData section so we can see what commands are run before that.

What ami are you using? what other resources are spun up in your template? the more info the better.

Comment: It's a bash directive, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install Odoo using *CloudFormation*? Can you share the *CloudFormation* template? Without that information, it'll be difficult to help you, but I'll still try pointing you in the right direction.

1. You don't need `sudo` in a *UserData* script since that script is always executed with `sudo` behind the scenes.
2. Look at the contents of `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` on the webserver. It'll contain the console output for your UserData script execution.